# copy text in froyo from web page including newlines?

Tags: browser, notes, copy-paste

I have just bought a new HTC Desire HD running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

I am trying to copy text from a rather vast archive of notes which I had built up on my old phone, which was running Symbian. The notes were saved using the ActiveNotes application, which is not available on Android, only on Symbian. ActiveNotes saves the notes as HTML files, which I can easily view on Android using the HTML viewer or web browser, or any other html reader (such as Dolphin).

I have tried to use the built-in copy/paste functionality by touch-and-hold then "select all" and copy. This does not seem to work in HTML viewer, but does work in the browser or Dolphin. However, ActiveNotes stores the newlines in my notes using paragraph tags (HTML <p> tags) and these are not correctly copied by the built-in text copier. Because of this, all the text appears as one long string, without any line breaks, when I paste it into my Android notes application (or indeed any Android notes application such as Messaging). This is very annoying as many of my notes are in excess of 100 lines long.

A number of copy/paste apps seem to be available which use the "Share Page" option on the menu. I use this when accessing my page through a URL through Astro, so the URL looks something like "content://com.metago.astro.filesystem/mnt/sdcard/Activenotes/NoteNameHere.html?text/plain". The two copy/paste apps I tried were "Any Web Copy" and "Copy To Clipboard". The latter seems to always copy just the URL (rather than the page content) to the clipboard. The former copies the web page text to the clipboard for "http://" links but refuses to for these "content://" links. Even when the web page text is copied to the clipboard (e.g. from an internet page), it still seems to be devoid of any newlines for much of the page.

Since the source of these files is actually viewable (e.g. in the plain text editor) there MUST be a way to copy the content of the pages including newlines. I could do this conversion myself on PC manually for every single file, but this would take a very long time and I would much rather be able to convert files on-demand on my phone using the above method. However, I am at a bit of a loss as to how to preserve the newlines. I hope that someone more experienced might be able to help or recommend an application that could help.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't help you with the copy-paste, I do recommend using an automatic solution to convert the files.  Conversion to PDF might help if Adobe Reader for Android will let you copy newlines, or you could have a `<br />` tag inserted after every paragraph, etc.